# Check if SQL field contains data, if so echo data, else return text field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that is filled out once a year per customer, but some fields stay constant (birthday for example). So my goal is when a new customer fills out the form for the first time the birthday field is a text box, but after they fill out the form the first time and come back next year it just displays their birthday but does not allow them to edit it (echo's the birthday, not simply shows it in the text box).

What I have now is below, the goal of this statement is to check if there is a value in the SQL field, if so echo that value, else echo a text box. I keep getting an error when I try and load the form and I think its just a syntax error somewhere.

```
<?php
if($bday!="") //if bday field is not empty
{
echo $bday; //display bday field value
}
else
{           
echo '<input type=text name=bday size=12 maxlength=12 value='<?php echo htmlentities ($bday, ENT_QUOTES) ?>'>'; //else echo the text box
}
?>
```

Comment: ***What is the error!?*** It's easy enough to deduce in your case, but please show us errors if you get them! Better yet, try to figure out what they're trying to tell you yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already writing PHP, so you don't have to use the opening and closing tags again in your echo statement. Use string concatenation (using a dot) instead. Try this:

```
echo '<input type=text name=bday size=12 maxlength=12 value="'.htmlentities($bday, ENT_QUOTES).'">';
```

However, if $bday=="", why use it as the value for the textbox?

Comment: Perfect, that worked! Yeah and you are right I don't need to use it as the value anymore, I was pulling this value in before just to display it (where the user could still edit) but can take that out now.